# Javascript library or code that can convert an "uncompressed" bitcoin private key to a compressed one

Tags: private-key, segregated-witness, javascript

I forked a pretty old brain wallet generator: https://dvdbng.github.io/memwallet/ -- Currently it generates uncompressed bitcoin private keys. Is there a javascript library that can convert an uncompressed bitcoin private key to a compressed one? Or what is the required fundamental knowledge to know in order to compress a bitcoin private key?

Comment: ECC/Bitcoin private keys are neither compressed nor uncompressed. They are sometimes stored with a flag indicating whether the _public_ key will be compressed; in particular [WIF](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) adds a byte '01' to the end of an encoded private key to indicate its public key should be compressed. Related (but no code) https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43090/why-are-compressed-private-keys-typically-longer-than-their-uncompressed-counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Oops sorry I read "public key". A private key can be converted to a public key that is either compressed on uncompressed, but raw EC private keys are always 32 bytes. That website appears to be generating what is called [Wallet Input Format (WIF)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) which is used to transfer private keys between software applications. To convert to hex:

1. decode using Base58Check
2. drop 1st byte
3. If the WIF started with K or L, then also drop the last byte (0x01) which denotes the private key corresponds to a compressed public key

Example:

WIF: `5J2zgrqrMFcnWALe5foVPzaA8VLNJV8zoZn37WfQCu8DYDCVmXE`

1. Base58Check decoded: `801cdb52e9a9fa3e089c7b8713218df4a7924b2109b159df480960ddfe73e221c3`
2. Drop 1st byte:
   `1cdb52e9a9fa3e089c7b8713218df4a7924b2109b159df480960ddfe73e221c3`
3. N/A

**old**:

Given a public key, e.g.

`04a097026e876544a0e40f9ca836435560af4470e161bf60c23465dcb3151c947d1cbe052875211972107e25fca8dd939f1c6e749a43862673ec5cf7a8567f2d95`

The `0x04` designates this as an uncompressed public key, where the next 32 bytes are the `x` value and the final 32 bytes are the `y` value of the point on the elliptic curve, respectfully.

To convert from an uncompressed public key to a compressed public key, you can omit the `y` value because the `y` value can be solved for using the equation of the elliptic curve: `y² = x³ + 7`, given `x`. Since the equation solves for `y²`, `y` could be either positive or negative. So, `0x02` is prepended for positive `y` values, and `0x03` is prepended for negative ones. If the `y` coordinate is even, then it corresponds to a positive number. If odd, then it is negative. Since the y value ends in `0xee`, which is even, and therefore positive, the compressed version of the public key becomes:

`03a097026e876544a0e40f9ca836435560af4470e161bf60c23465dcb3151c947d`

### Javascript

You can use [`bitcoinjs-lib`](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) to convert:

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')

const pubkeyBuf = Buffer.from('04a097026e876544a0e40f9ca836435560af4470e161bf60c23465dcb3151c947d1cbe052875211972107e25fca8dd939f1c6e749a43862673ec5cf7a8567f2d95', 'hex')
const pubkey = bitcoin.ECPair.fromPublicKey(pubkeyBuf)
pubkey.publicKey.toString('hex')

'03a097026e876544a0e40f9ca836435560af4470e161bf60c23465dcb3151c947d'
```

Comment: OP was asking about converting private keys.